# Is it okay to call rest API in every 5 seconds to receive update Android/iOS UX?

Tags: android, ios, rest, server-push

We are building one mobile (Android & iOS) application where we need to update UX based on the data we receive from back-end server. The value of data from server might change in a range of 1 to 20 minutes. Is it good to call the rest API in every 5 seconds considering there can be chances of 120,000 calls to that API in one minute? Please also propose any solution if any of you came across similar problem & solved it.

Comment: You should rephrase your post and first explain what you are trying to achieve (update your UI frequently). You should define what the expected result is in different app scenarios (opened, in background, terminated). Then what you are considering/trying and what are your concerns. It might be that you are just looking for WebSocket.

Comment: @MaticOblak very simple, the data should be upto date as soon as user sees it on UX.

Answer (score 1):

No, and you'd spend a fortune on cloud hosting as you scale up if you did that.  Look into push messaging instead-  that's where the server sends a message to the client when data changes.  That's how things like messaging apps work, rather than polling.